# Showing that a certain group of a number field is dense in $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and $O_K$ to be its ring of integers. Let $M$ be a non-zero ideal of $O_K$. In an passage I am reading (related to Hecke characters), it states:

the group $\{\alpha \in K^* : \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod M \}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}^*$.

There is no explanation. I am not sure what the notation $\alpha \equiv 1 \pmod M$ means when $\alpha$ is not in $O_K$... I would also appreciate if  someone could explain how to show this group is dense in $\mathbb{C}^*$.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You are definitely missing some detail, because it is quite possible that $K$ is entirely real, and thus not possibly dense in the complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually for imaginary quadratic field. I fixed the typo

Comment: Remark: since that group is $1+O_KM \supset 1+O_K\alpha$ for some nonzero $\alpha$, it suffices to prove that $O_K$ itself is dense in $\Bbb C$. Do you see how to do this?

Comment: What does it mean for $\alpha\equiv 1\pmod M$ when $\alpha\in K^{*}$ (rather than just $\alpha\in O_K$?)

Comment: @GregMartin I see. Could I possibly get a hint on how to show $O_K$ is dense? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke—$O_K$ itself isn't dense in $\Bbb C$ (think $\Bbb Z[i]$ as an example). But for example, $\Bbb Q O_K$ is dense in $\Bbb C$.